# How to register a ArrayList with RegistrationHandlers in GWT?

Tags: gwt, mvp

in my current project i use the MVP-Pattern and i want to register a variable count of RegistrationHandlers for some checkboxes.

Something like this:
in my View.java i have:

```java
public ArrayList<HandlerRegistration> getCheckBoxesHandlers(ClickHandler handler) {
    ArrayList<HandlerRegistration> handlerRegistration= new ArrayList<HandlerRegistration>();
    for (Widget checkBox : availableSets) {
            handlerRegistration.add(((CheckBox)checkBox).addClickHandler(handler));
    }
    return handlerRegistration;
}
```

how can i handle this in my presenter? he following code doesn't work, because i don't know how to catch the handlers out of the array

```java
 display.getCheckBoxesHandlers(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            //TODO do something here

        }
    });
```

greetz,
destiny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use element id.

for each Widget checkBox in availableSets. Set an id.  checkBox.getElement().setId("checkbox"+i)

Then in your presenter you can check which id has been fired on event.getSource(). Cast it to Widget and get the id.

Comment: ah sry :( i have a mistake in my programcode. I setup my handlers if the checkBoxPanel is empty :-X but thank you for the tip with the id's :)